# Organize controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have these routes:

```
resources :forums do
    resources :topics do
        resources :posts
    end
end
```

These feels quite unorganized:

```
app/controllers
   |
   |-> forums_controller.rb
   |-> topics_controller.rb
   |-> posts_controller.rb
```

Is it possible to nest controller files somehow, so posts is "inside" topics, and topics is "inside" forums? How would the routes look?

Could I then easily administrate these controllers? Let's say forums are utterly off-limits to everyone who isn't signed in. Could I create a method that redirects all requests to the forums controller, topics controller and posts controller if the current_user is nil? Right now my all three of these controllers in my app have these such methods. Maybe I could make forums inherit from ApplicationController, but topics could inherit from forums, and posts inherit from topics? Then forum could have one, before_action filter that redirects un-signed-in users.

Comment: Ultimately you can do whatever you want, but this has nothing to do with shared methods. If you want to change the default structure, change your autoload paths in application.rb.

Comment: Oops, wrong name! Haha sorry edited this question pretty heavily

Answer (score 0):

You should leave them as they are now, add the method on ApplicationController and on each controller add the before_filter. You don't need the method repeated on each controller, only the before_filter call which is good since you probably don't want the filter to be applied on EVERY action so you could customize that on each controller.

I think you are misusing inheritance, posts does not inherit from topics, a topic has many posts and that should be specified at models, not controllers.